# likelihood function in Bayesian analysis?

Tags: distributions, bayesian, likelihood

Below is the distribution of my outcome variable y in the data, characterized by a heavy mass at zero and very long tail. Can you help me select an appropriate probability distribution for the likelihood in Bayesian analysis? My goal is to figure out the posterior mean y_bar and its credible intervals, given the data (as shown in the graph) as well as the likelihood and prior selected.

[image]

I've thought about using exponential or Poisson. But (1) the underlying sampling process is neither a wait-time or a count process, and (2) their density functions do not have the distinct features of the data, heavy mass at zero and long tail. So I ruled them out. The closest that I can think of is a gamma distribution with very small shape and rate parameter:

[image]

My question is, 
(1) Is the gamma distribution a good choice for the likelihood? And if yes, what kind of prior do you think I can consider?
(2) Why can't I just use the normal distribution as the likelihood?

Comment: The first question is: is $y$ count data? Does it take only discrete values or can it take any positive value?

Comment: Is there something that would create "extra" zeros.  For example, does something have to happen for a positive value with it otherwise being zero, or is zero a natural outcome of the process.  I deal with long tailed processes and so I find this fascinating.  Does this long tail make sense in some way?

Comment: Hi @Greenparker:  y is payments to customers. Usually it takes discrete values only. Does it make  sense to model the payment as count data, and why?

Comment: Hi @DaveHarris: Yes the zeros are something that have to happen before a payment y_i becomes positive. One can think of the zeros as the "embryonic" stage of the development of a payment.

Comment: @TCL You maybe looking for the [Tweedie distribution](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/10/a-note-on-tweedie.html)